# How to cancel attack command?

Tags: dont-starve, dont-starve-together

I frequently use <kbd>F</kbd> key and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> combo to attack mobs. Once in a while I accidentally give an attack command on my own allies, Chester mostly. What usually happens is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> command sometimes chooses to attack Chester instead of a friendly pig or an enemy, as I intended, and this attack causes all my allies to attack my beloved Chester. Or sometimes I accidentally attack a level 1-2 Spider den in the heat of battle, where I prefer to wait to become level 3 before harvesting.

Is there a way to cancel such an attack command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you can't cancel it for allies. Try attacking something else or moving away, but even that might not work.